# Compare mysql query to sql query

Tags: coldfusion

I am a lot more at home manipulating arrays and objects in php or javascript, and do next to no work with coldfusion.

I have one query pulling data from mysql. I would like to store results list or array ( or simpler approach)

WHile looping over a second query from msql that generates html output I need to see if one value is contained in prior mysql array or list.

Have tried playing with varierty of cf array/list methods and really not sure what best approach is to resolve following `if`. 
CF version is 9

```
<cfquery datasource="Mysql" name="premium_submitters">
  SELECT submitter_id from table  
</cfquery>
<!--- Need loop to store to array or list??--->

<cfquery datasource="Sql" name="main_data">
    SELECT * from table
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="main_data">
    <cfif #submiiter_id# <!---is in Mysql array/list return boolean---> >

    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Yes, it would belong [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401394/5770014)

Comment: Bumping a 9+ year old thread to change one word is probably not the best use of editing time :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ValueList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d19.html) to get the value of one column of a query into a list.

```
<cfquery datasource="Mysql" name="premium_submitters">
  SELECT submitter_id from table  
</cfquery>

<cfset submittersList = ValueList(premium_submitters.submitter_id)>

<cfquery datasource="Sql" name="main_data">
    SELECT * from table
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="main_data">
    <cfif ListFind(submittersList, main_data.submitter_id) gt 0>
      <!--- is in list, do whatever --->
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This is one of my original attemps also. I get following error `The ValueList() function has an invalid parameter: premium_submitters.submitter_id. `

Comment: Have you done a `cfdump` on the premium_submitters query to make sure it is populated?

Comment: yes I just resolved the issue, there is a difference in spelling of the 2 fields that I hadn't noticed, then when trying to figure out which list method to use I overlooked the typo difference